# How do I enable password request after hibernation in lubuntu 14.04?

Tags: password, hibernate

I'm running lubuntu 14.04 and have finally managed to enable hibernation.

However, after hibernation, the system will start without asking for my password.

I've tried several advices posted for older versions of ubuntu, but none were successful.

Comment: you should accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

Open the menu, go to `Preferences - Light Locker Settings`. Then under `Locking` click the slider next to `Lock on suspend` from OFF to OonN.

Comment: In lubuntu, system settings are organized a little different  ... I found "light locker settings" and there was able to switch "lock on suspend" from "off" to "on". That was it!

Comment: Yeah, just checked on my lubuntu machine! If that worked, don't forget to accept the answer!